# How to use lower() with multiple lists in python?

Tags: python, string, list, lowercase

I'm trying to find certain keywords in the  html source code of multiple websites. I want my crawler to find these keywords regardless whether they are written uppercased, or lowercased in the website's html source code. To get this done I've tried using the `.lower()` query in this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

def keywords():
    with open('urls.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Peter\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

        list_1 = ['keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3']
        list_2 = ['keyword 4', 'keyword 5', 'keyword 6']
        list_3 = ['keyword 7', 'keyword 8']

        keywords = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

        for row in csv_reader:
            driver.get(row[0])
            html = driver.page_source

            for searchstring in keywords:
                if searchstring.lower() in html.lower():
                    print (row[0], searchstring, 'found')

                else:
                    print (row[0], searchstring, 'not found')

print keywords()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

So i found out that `.lower()` doesn't work on lists, works only with strings.

I've googled the error and my issue but didn't found a solution to my problem. Any suggestion how i can solve this with my current script?

Comment: I assume .lower() turns the string it's used on lowercase; If so, you should run it on every item in the list..You can easily use a for loop for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your keywords as a list of strings in list of list of strings.
Here i am already lowering the keywords.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

def keywords():
    with open('urls.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Peter\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

        list_1 = ['keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3']
        list_2 = ['keyword 4', 'keyword 5', 'keyword 6']
        list_3 = ['keyword 7', 'keyword 8']

        lower_list = lambda x: x.lower()
        keywords = map(lower_list, list_1 + list_2 + list_3)

        for row in csv_reader:
            driver.get(row[0])
            html = driver.page_source
```

Comment: Why not simply `keywords = map(lower_list, list_1 + list_2 + list_3)`? Also it's not clear whether OP is using Python 2 or 3(they're using `print()` as function), hence it is always better to use a list-comprehension(it's fast compared to map with lambda). `map` would exhaust after first iteration in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function, like so

```
l = ['Item 1', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 3', 'ItEM 4']
m = map(str.lower, l)
print(list(m))
```

This gets you `['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']`

map applies a function to every element of an iterable and returns a map object, which is itself an iterable. You can just do `map(str.lower, keywords)` in your `for searchstring in map(str.lower, keywords)`

EDIT: Oops, didn't notice that you wanted to combine three lists that way. You could flatten the lists with `[item.lower() for sublist in keywords for item in sublist]` and get the results you want.

Comment: Call `lower()` within list-comprehension itself `[item.lower() for sublist in keywords for item in sublist]`?